# Number of roots of a Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove there exists at most one $n$-tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb Z^n$ satisfying the following equation:$$\dfrac{1}{x_1}+\dfrac{1}{x_2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{x_n}+\dfrac{1}{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}=1$$I don't know where to start. I know that the equation $x_1+\cdots+x_n=x_1x_2\cdots x_n$ has finite answers in $\Bbb N^n$ but is there any relation between these things? How can one solve such a question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you mean "finitely many answers", then that is what you should write. Did you mean "some answers, each one of which is finite"? In that case, you should write "finite answers".

Comment: I mean finitely many finite answers.... In fact the answers are bounded if I have got you correctly...

Comment: I can do $n=1.$

Comment: Did $n=2.$ Actually two answers, but one if we order the variables.

Comment: Yes but such permutations are taken in account likewise

Comment: This seems related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zn%C3%A1m%27s_problem (including "improper" Znám's problem). It looks that the claim from the question is false, see also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZnamsProblem.html with two solutions for the "proper" Znám's problem for $n=5$: $(2,3,7,47,395)$ and $(2,3,11,23,31)$, plus many more for bigger $n$.

Comment: At a guess, the intended claim is "at least one".

Comment: @MishaLavrov one sequence that works is the first $n$ entries at https://oeis.org/A000058

Answer (score 2):

One sequence of answers that works for every $n$ is
$$  2  $$
$$ 2, 3 $$
$$ 2,3,7 $$
$$ 2,3,7,43   $$
$$ 2,3,7,43, 1807   $$
where each new maximum entry is [one added to the product of the previous entries.](https://oeis.org/A000058)

If we have already solved in dimension $n-1,$ as in $S+1 = T,$ where $T$ is the product of all $n-1$ variables, appending a new $x_n = T + 1$ gives
$$  x_n S + T +1 = x_n T,  $$
$$ (T+1) (T-1) + T + 1 = (T+1)T,  $$
$$  T^2 +T = T^2 +T  $$